# How to solve this recursion question I saw during job interview?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I was asked this question during an online assessment (I'm a student looking for an SDE internship) and couldn't solve it in time (I was only given 5 minutes...). Do you guys think 5 minutes for this question is enough btw? I'm just kinda curious how good everyone else is.

Anyways, here's the question:

> You are given two tuples of integers `(A, B)` and `(C, D)`. 
> There are two operations you can do:
>  `(A + B, B)` 
>  `(A, A + B)`
>  Write a function that returns `True` if `(A, B)` can be transformed into `(C, D)` using the two operations, `False` otherwise.

Example:

```
Input: A = 2, B = 3, C = 8, D = 11
Output: True
```

I'll put what I 'thought' I wrote during the assessment here (I'm only 70% sure). It seems to be working fine and I'm not sure why it wouldn't pass the tests. If you guys know what the problem is, or the correct solution, please let me know!

```
def func(A, B, C, D):
    if A == C and B == D:
        return True
    if A > C or B > D:  
        return False

    return func(A + B , B, C, D) or func(A, A + B, C, D)
```

Comment: What if any of the numbers are negative?

Comment: `func(1,-1,0,-1)` seems like it should return `True`.

Comment: Hmmm with 5 minutes I thought in something like `return  ((C - A) % B == 0 and (D - B) % A == 0)` but it will throw an exception if `A or B == 0`

Comment: @Latra it is not correct. The counterexample is `(2, 3, 13, 8)`.

Comment: @oleksii-tambovtsev hmmmm `(2, 3, 13, 8)` should be true? I'm missing something then

Comment: @Latra Maybe I misunderstood the task but I thought that on every step you can add the second element to the first or vice versa. So you can have `(2, 3) -> (2 + 3, 3) -> (5, 3 + 5) -> (5 + 8, 8) = (13, 8)`.

Comment: Could be, and based on @Nathan code you are right.

Comment: Maybe your function definition needs to be `func(A, B, C, D, org_A, org_B):` and return value as `func(A + org_B , B, C, D, org_A, org_B) or func(A , B + org_A, C, D, org_A, org_B)`. The problem statement is a little ambiguous.

Comment: What exactly are the operations? You've given examples, but it's not clear which if any of the A's and B's in the example are representing the elements of an arbitrary tuple and which represent the elements of the tuple you're initially given.

Comment: funny how this question got so many upvotes while everyone in the comments complain about an unclear question. may the upvoters help making this question better for all?

Comment: What are the limitations for `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`? I have an answer of `O(N^2)` if `A, B, C, D < N`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a full solution, which will work for mixtures of positive and negative integers.

I would not expect a prospective intern to work this out in 5 minutes.  And the fact that they expected you to I'd call a red flag.

```
def op_test(a, b, c, d):
    if a == c and b == d:
        return True

    if max(a, b) < 0 and min(a, b) < min(c, d):
        # No way to increase min(a, b)
        return False
    elif 0 < min(a, b) and max(c, d) < max(a, b):
        # No way to decrease max(a, b)
        return False

    # The 0 checks are to avoid endless recursion.
    if 0 != a and op_test(a, a+b, c, d):
        return True

    if 0 != b and op_test(a+b, b, c, d):
        return True

    return False
```

Comment: @SaiPardhu I know it is.  Which is why it is a useful red flag to note that they asked questions people reasonably shouldn't know.  And if the interviewer then demonstrates how smart they are by showing that they know how to do it - run the other way.

Answer (score 1):

There's a unique path down from the target (assuming positive integers), so go that direction to avoid a large search space.

I.e. always decrease the larger coord by the smaller, or any
integer multiple of the smaller that doesn't overshoot your target.

E.g. 8,11 -> 8,3 -> 2,3 is the unique path down from the target attained by decreasing the larger coord by the largest mult of the smaller that doesn't overshoot.

---

We can use similar logic anytime the starting & ending coordinates are in the same quadrant.

---

There's no solution if the start is in quadrants I or III while the end is in II or IV. For the reverse situation, I think (but haven't proven) that there is a solution iff gcd(A,B) = gcd(C,D). I'll get back to this and edit my answer after the kiddos go to bed.

Comment: "There's a unique path": how ?

Comment: Reduce the larger by the smaller @yves

Comment: Oooops, right !

Comment: This is right, and assuming you do repeated subtractions efficiently (for example using the modulo operator) this runs in logarithmic time.

Comment: But they didn't tell you to assume positive integers.

Comment: @btilly That's why I mentioned it, though this works as well if we start out with both coords negative.

Comment: @btilly Same idea works if both the source & target have one coord pos & one coord neg (since we can't ever exit the quadrant we start in). Only case left to solve is if the starting point is mixed and the end is pos/pos or neg/neg.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful, if A==0 or B==0 you could get an infinite recursion and blow your stack.  You need to detect that condition and return False.

```
return (B != 0 and func(A + B , B, C, D)) or (A != 0 and func(A, A + B, C, D))
```

Comment: The existing guard conditions don't work when integers can be positive or negative.

Comment: @btilly I didn't say this was the *only* problem with the code.  It was just the first thing that jumped out at me.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps

```
def recursively(A,B,C,D):

    if A < C :
        A = A + B
        return recursively(A,B,C,D)
    if B < D:
        B = A + B
        return recursively(A,B,C,D)
    if A  == C and B == D:
        return True
    if A > C and B > D:
        return False
    return False


print(recursively(2,3,8,11))
```

Comment: This code doesn't always work, for example (1, 3) to (5, 4). The solution is (1, 3) -> (1, 4) -> (5, 4), but this code starts with the step (1, 3) -> (4, 3) and from there it's impossible to get to the target.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using BFS or DFS approach. I'd go with BFS as it'll get you there(the solution state) the fastest. Also, make sure you have a threshold to stop your loop for the cases where there is no solution (can't reach C,D)